# Want to Add Custom Google Calendar Notifications to Events Created from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently working on creating a Google Sheet that would allow me to create calendar events (reminders) for when certain reports are due for me.

Basically, on the basis of a given opening date, I have 5 different types of reports due, some at different intervals (ie, 45 days from the open date, 6 months, 12 months). I've been able to modify a sample I found online (http://www.adammcfarland.com/2013/08/09/tutorial-using-google-spreadsheets-to-update-a-google-calendar-our-new-vacation-management-system/), customizing a Google Sheet to generate due dates for each type of report, and create calendar entries based on those due dates. It's actually really cool and powerful.

Unfortunately, I'm stumbling when it comes to creating notifications for the different reports. I know how to create default notifications within the Google Calendar interface, but the quirk I'm currently trying to address is that of these various reports, not all require as much time to complete, so I'm looking to create notifications specific to each report type, and I'm thus far been wholly unable to get things working.

Here's a copy of the script I'm using.

```
enter code herefunction pushToCalendar() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,5);
  var values = range.getValues();   
  var updateRange = sheet.getRange('G1'); 


 var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('jk.com_5e9gk4@group.calendar.google.com')


  updateRange.setFontColor('red');

  var numValues = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 


if ((values[i][0].length > 0) && (values[i][2].length > 0)) {


  if (values[i][3] != 'y') {                       


    var newEventTitle = 'Note Due: ' + values[i][0] + ' - ' + values[i][2];
    var newEvent = calendar.createAllDayEvent(newEventTitle, values[i][1]);


    var newEventId = newEvent.getId();


    sheet.getRange(i+2,4).setValue('y');
    sheet.getRange(i+2,5).setValue(newEventId);

}
```

Where "values[i][2]" corresponds to the type of report due.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to addreminder just after creating event based on a table. See the code below :

```
function pushToCalendar() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    //Define reminder, value in minute and lower 4weeks (=40320 minutes)
    var reminder = {"type1":1440,//=1 day
                    "type2":7200,//5days
                    "type3":20160//2weeks
                   };
    //End define reminder
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,5);
    var values = range.getValues();   
    var updateRange = sheet.getRange('G1'); 
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('jk.com_5e9gk4@group.calendar.google.com')
    updateRange.setFontColor('red');
    var numValues = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
      if ((values[i][0].length > 0) && (values[i][2].length > 0)) {
        if (values[i][3] != 'y') {                       
          var newEventTitle = 'Note Due: ' + values[i][0] + ' - ' + values[i][2];
          var newEvent = calendar.createAllDayEvent(newEventTitle, values[i][1]);
          //Add reminder
          //For that we assume you well created the reminder var and all type have the amount of minutes define if not you must implement the check in he code
          newEvent.addEmailReminder(reminder[values[i][2]]);
          //End add reminder
          var newEventId = newEvent.getId();
          sheet.getRange(i+2,4).setValue('y');
          sheet.getRange(i+2,5).setValue(newEventId);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I added some comments in the code for you.

Stéphane

Comment: This answers the question and don't even the OP gave you +1 ? Amazing. Here's mine :)